# nodejs connect usage of built in modules -> method not found

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

when I call this node.js file

```
var connect = require('connect');
var app = connect();
app.use(connect.static('public'));
app.listen(3000);
```

I immediately get

```
app.use(connect.static('public'));
                      ^
TypeError: Object function createServer() {
  function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
  merge(app, proto);
  merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
  app.route = '/';
  app.stack = [];
  return app;
} has no method 'static'
```

Using Connect 3.0.1.  Are there changes with the integrated modules?
If yes, how does it work then?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

big changes coming with connect 3: middleware modules not included any longer. Find them at [github.com/expressjs](http://github.com/expressjs). "static" is now "serve-static". It needs to be installed separately with:

`npm install serve-static`

The above code should now look like this:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var app = connect();
app.use(serveStatic('public'));
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: this should be in documentation... sad is that it is not the case :(

Comment: has been added now, at least here: http://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/Readme.md

Comment: I guess they are still in the process of updating the docs, still not updated here: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/

Comment: For the project I'm working with, I needed to change `serveStatic('public')` to `serveStatic(__dirname)`

Comment: Related: I also had to install `gulp-serve-index` and replace `connect.directory('app')` with `serveIndex('app')`

Answer (score 1):

I had to install connect and serve-static

```
npm install connect
```

then type:

```
npm install serve-static
```

The code below will give you a nice message telling you your server is connected to port 3000.

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var app = connect();
var port = 3000;
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname));
app.listen(port);
console.log('You are connected at port '+port);
```